# Ways to express the relationship between a latent variable and observables

Tags: terminology, latent-variable

How do I express concisely the idea that the values of a number of observables is determined stochastically by the value of a latent variable?

Can I say:

- The value of the latent variable is expressed in the values of the observables,
- the latent variable is materialized in the observables (ugh, probably not),
- the values of the observables reflect that of the latent variable?

Optimally, I would like to have multiple ways of saying this in different contexts as I'll be saying that quite a lot.

(And, sorry, I guess to ask this question more precisely I would have to know the answer.)

Comment: If you insist on a lay or a substantial wording rather then mathematical, you might say something like "a latent factor `stands behind / drives / is the essence in` the observed variables". Note that the term "latent variable" is typically used only for a _group_ of interdependent observables. For a single observed variable, we may say that it has its "underlying variable" plus some measurement disturbance.

Comment: You could say that your observed variables are noisy measurements of the latent variable, or simply that the latent variable causally influences the observed variables, if either of those are the case. However, you might do best by picking a single expression, defining it carefully, and using it over and over. Better to be boring and clear than interesting but vague!